# How to determine why the JFrame was moved (Windows, JDK6)

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrmMain extends JFrame implements ComponentListener
{

FrmMain()
{
    super("Moves & Resize");
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(512,384));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addComponentListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void componentMoved( ComponentEvent ev )
{
    int state = getExtendedState();
    if( (state&JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)==JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH )
    {
        System.out.println("Moved, maximized");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Moved, not maximized");
    }
}
public void componentResized( ComponentEvent ev )
{
    int state = getExtendedState();
    if( (state&JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)==JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH )
    {
        System.out.println("Resized, maximized");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Resized, not maximized");
    }
}
public void componentShown( ComponentEvent ev )
{
}
public void componentHidden( ComponentEvent ev )
{
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                FrmMain mainwin = new FrmMain();
            }
        }
    );
}

}
```

I want to determine whether the frame was resized/moved due to being maximized, or simply dragged around by user. Surprisingly, the code above outputs (after I press "maximize" button on the frame):

```
Moved, not maximized
Resized, maximized
```

That means, the update of window state happens after calling `componentMoved` and before calling `componentResized`. So, how do I find out, if the window is being maximized, inside `componentMoved` event?

Comment: `moved` are you meaning moved on the one monitor screen, moved from one monitor to the 2nd. or I miss undertood ...

Comment: Maybe a WindowStateListener will help?

Comment: *"Surprisingly, the code above outputs.."*  Unsurprisingly, the code snippet does not compile.  For better chance of testing by others (confirmation of result), please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @camickr, no, it won't help. I need this info inside `windowMoved` handler. I can write a hundred various hacks, of course, but life would be much easier if the behaviour of `windowMoved` and `windowResized` handlers were consistent.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, of course it doesn't compile, as I threw out all the unnecessary lines. Anyway, I corrected the example. Dunno about the line lengths, though. 62 chars is a bit too short.

Comment: I don't quite understand if the results I get differ from yours.  When the frame 1st appears I am seeing 3 lines of output.  When I maximize the frame I see a further 2, being.. `Moved, maximized` & `Resized, maximized`.  Is that the output you were *expecting* to see?  (The 1st three lines of output all include the word "not" BTW).

Comment: @Aliaksei Hayeu there are two ways write 200 - 1T code lines if you don't want to use `WindowStateListener` and listening for all these changes correctly, or only four code lines with `WindowStateListener`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(state&JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) != 0
```

as MAXIMIZED_BOTH is two bits of horizontally and vertically maximized.
Under JSE 7 I do get "moved, maximized."

I would not tamper with the order of moved and resized event. Trying to reimplement the close box is a bad idea too.

You could post your own event on moved, which then would come after the resized event.